# How do I display todays date on SSRS report?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I want to show up `Todays date` as `report generated date` on SSRS report.

How can i do that ?

should I use any variable  ?

please help me I'm newbie to SSRS.

For example refer this image:
[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

date column 1:

```
=formatdatetime(today)
```

Comment: where i need to put this expression exactly... sorry to ask i'm new to ssrs

Comment: For instance in Textbox. (Add textbox to your report from report items list, then right click on the added textbox and choose expression).

Comment: if you wish to format your  date you can use `=format((today),"dd/MM/yyyy")`

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
=FORMAT(Cdate(today), "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

or

```
=FORMAT(Cdate(today), "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

or

```
=FORMAT(Cdate(today), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

or

```
=Report Generation Date: " & FORMAT(Cdate(today), "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

**You should format the date in the same format your customer (internal or external) wants to see the date**. For example In one of my servers it is running on American date format (MM-dd-yyyy) and on my reports I must ensure the dates displayed are European (yyyy-MM-dd).

Answer (score 11):

You can also drag and drop "Execution Time" item from Built-in Fields list.

Answer (score 11):

to display date and time, try this:

```
=Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can place a text-box to the report and add an expression with the following value in it:

```
="Report generation date:  " & Format(Globals!ExecutionTime,"dd/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt" )
```

Answer (score 3):

In the text box that contains the header, you can use an expression to get the date. Try something like

```
    ="Report Generation Date: " & Today()
```

right click in the text box in the layout view. At the bottom of the list you'll see the expression option. There you will be able to enter the code. This option will allow you to avoid adding a second textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Just simple use

```
=Format(today(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you may use the build-in function

```
Globals!ExecutionTime
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inset Test box in the design area of the SSRS report.
2. Right-click on the Textbox and scroll down and click on the Expression tab
3. just type the given expression in the expression area:     =format(Today,"dd/MM/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in function
=Globals!ExecutionTime
and make the value = [&ExecutionTime] (or whatever you want to call it)

You can also add the user Id of the person generating the report using the built in function

=User!UserID

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).